# Issues with tKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first time ever writing here.
Also my first time actually coding.

I've made a code but have issues running it due to tKinter not seeming to exist, even though I've specifically installed python from the official webpage and also ticked the tcl/tk options.

When trying to launch my code i get this error:

File "C:\Users\Nikla\Desktop\roligttest.py", line 44, in 
exp_bar = tk.Progressbar(exp_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate', value=20, maximum=100)
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Progressbar'

---

This error then leads me to investigating if tkinter is installed correctly. But to my surprise I get this message:

PS C:\Users\Nikla> pip uninstall tkinter
WARNING: Skipping tkinter as it is not installed.
PS C:\Users\Nikla> pip install tkinter
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

---

Any ideas?

And keep in mind, this is my ABSOLUTE first time trying to code something.

Thanks in advance,
Niklas

I tried reinstalling tkinter, it did not exist
I tried uninstalling tkinter, it did not exist
I tried installing tkinter, it tells me "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writable

I also get "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter"-message.

Comment: You have Tkinter installed; it simply *doesn't* have anything called `Progressbar`.  That's a part of the `ttk` submodule, not Tkinter itself.  (And `pip` is of no use here anyway, that's not how Tkinter is distributed - it's either installed with Python itself, or as a separate system-level package.)

Comment: Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `tkk` package.

```
from tkinter import ttk

pb = tkk.Progressbar(exp_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate', value=20, maximum=100)
```

[Reference](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-progressbar/)

Also tkinter is a built in package and can't remove

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

You helped me sort out my first code ever and gave me this result:

https://imgur.com/t9lUPmG

Cheers!